# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected transient int java.util.AbstractList.modCount accessible

Tags: java, scala

I am getting the issue below:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected transient int java.util.AbstractList.modCount accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @43393097
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
```

The fix is widely-documented on the net: use JVM options

--illegal-access=permit

or

--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED.

The former was removed after JDK 11. I started with JDK 17 and have now tried both Amazon and Open JDK 11. Neither of these options used with a JDK version 11 eliminates the error, nor does using both at once. I've tried every permutation (and also using --illegal-access=warn).

I'm launching the app like this:

```
me in ~/dev/project on branch main > java --version
openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode)
me in ~/dev/project on branch main >                          
me in ~/dev/project on branch main > java -jar --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED out/server/assembly.dest/out.jar
```

Everything I read suggests that using --add-opens=java.base... will fix the issue on JDK11. It does not.

Using --illegal-access=permit, either along or with --add-opens, also doesn't work.

There's no chance the way a jar is *built* can influence this, right? It's strictly a runtime permissions thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this 3 options

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
```

this worked for me with an error message very similar to yours for jdk 17

Comment: Worked for me with only the first option (must be a simpler issue for me). Problem was using xstream (XML) and I am wondering if I can set my module or pom to avoid having to use the options. Java 19.